# Foundation NSObject.h without - (id)init method

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, xcode5, nsobject, foundation

I'm starting to study and develop my first mac app, I'm following a guide about Object-c and Cocoa, but I'm stuck because I can't find the - (id)init method inside NSObject @interface, I use Xcode 5.1.1 and OSX 10.9.4.

Comment: I think you should use Ctrl+CMD+J - it will jump you to definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the `objc` `NSObject.h` file, which is imported by the foundation one (`#import <objc/NSObject.h>`):

```
__OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING(__MAC_10_0, __IPHONE_2_0)
OBJC_ROOT_CLASS
OBJC_EXPORT
@interface NSObject <NSObject> {
    Class isa  OBJC_ISA_AVAILABILITY;
}

+ (void)load;

+ (void)initialize;
- (id)init;
//...
```

Comment: Ok, objc is a different source of NSObject, what is the difference with Foundation source. It's possible that inside objc there are Deprecated Methods?